# How to set client local endpoint - Java RMI

Tags: java, rmi

So I have a very basic client-server program running on my local lan network.
The program consists in the server being a permanent listener, adding every client who connects to his ip to a list of observers and updating them every 5 seconds (Client Extends UnicastRemoteObject).
The problem is that I don't know why the client creates a reference using an unknown ip address.

This is what I usually get from the client, if I type `System.out.println(this)`:

```
RmiClient[UnicastServerRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[192.168.56.1:64199](local),objID:[32218df3:16acc934a0a:-7fff, 8241015111525045915]]]]
```

I did some research and I found that ip address belongs to my VirtualBox Host-Only Newtork interface, so when I disable this I get the correct infos:

```
RmiClient[UnicastServerRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[192.168.1.3:64307](local),objID:[1b156947:16acc999fa5:-7fff, 6095931207093481175]]]]
```

Which is the correct ip of this machine on my lan.
My question is how do I make this work without permanent disabling the interface?
Also if I set server and client on different machines, I get a RemoteException when the server tries to update the  clients because it tries to contact 192.168.56.1 and obviously fails.

Comment: This is item A.1 in the Oracle RMI FAQ. You need to set the system property `java.rmi.server.hostname` in your object-exporting JVMs prior to exporting any remote objects from them if the default IP address isn't what you want.

Comment: @user207421 Your answer in partially correct since I alredy had set the propery on both client and server before any exportation, the problem was the client extending `UnicastRemoteObject`

Comment: My *comment* is entirely correct, and extending `UnicastRemoteObject` or not has nothing to do with it. You have to set the property before exporting any remote object, and constructing a `UnicastRemoteObject` constitutes exporting a remote object. Possibly you were unaware of this, or you have some other understanding of 'export'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved! The problem consisted in the Client extending `UnicastRemoteObject`.
Apparently I had to set the property `java.rmi.server.hostname` in both client and server applications, but in the client that wasn't working because of the extension.
So I managed to solve by eliminating the extension and adding the following code:
`UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(this, port);`

This way the propery works correctly on the client.

Comment: The property works correctly either way. Your problem lay elsewhere.

Comment: As I wrote before, I solves the issued deleting the extension and only this way the program works fine. I don't know why you are saying there must be another cause. Anyway, the problem is solved as you can see.

Comment: The system property and the extension have nothing to do with each other. That's why there must have been another cause. Most likely you weren't setting the property correctly, or early enough, as I've said numerous times here.